# CakePHP 3.x: updating multiple records

Tags: cakephp-3.0, updating, multiple-records

I have read [Saving Entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-entities) and [Patching HasMany and BelongsToMany](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#patching-hasmany-and-belongstomany) but I'm having trouble with patchEntities() because it doesn't seem to merge the data. After patching, the result of $entities is 1 'empty'/'new' record instead of 2 containing an id. Saving the entity results in a foreign key error.

I am new to CakePHP 3.0 so I may very well do something wrong here. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

My code:

```
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
    $list = $this->RecipyIngredients->find()
        ->contain(['Ingredients', 'Quantities'])
        ->where(['RecipyIngredients.recipy_id' => $recipy_id])
        ->toArray();

    $entities = $this->RecipyIngredients->patchEntities($list, $this->request->data);

    debug($entities);
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        //$this->RecipyIngredients->save($entity);
        //debug($entity);
    }
}
```

The various results:

```
debug($this->request->data);
[
    'RecipyIngredients' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'id' => '1',
            'amount' => '25',
            'quantity_id' => '1',
            'ingredient_id' => '269',
            'remark' => ''
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'id' => '2',
            'amount' => '300',
            'quantity_id' => '1',
            'ingredient_id' => '88',
            'remark' => ''
        ],
    ]
]

debug($list);
[
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\RecipyIngredient) {

        'id' => (int) 1,
        'recipy_id' => (int) 1,
        'ingredient_id' => (int) 269,
        'quantity_id' => (int) 1,
        'amount' => '25',
        'amount_in_gram' => (int) 25,
        'remark' => '',
        'grouping_term' => null,
        'version' => (int) 1,
        'created' => null,
        'modified' => null,
        'quantity' => object(App\Model\Entity\Quantity) {

            'id' => (int) 1,
            'name' => 'gram',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                'name' => true,
                'ingredients' => true,
                'recipy_ingredients' => true,
                'shoppinglist' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Quantities'

        },
        'ingredient' => object(App\Model\Entity\Ingredient) {

            'id' => (int) 269,
            'name' => 'citroensap',
            'average_weight' => null,
            'recipy_id' => null,
            'quantity_id' => null,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                'name' => true,
                'average_weight' => true,
                'recipy_id' => true,
                'quantity_id' => true,
                'recipy' => true,
                'quantity' => true,
                'shoppinglist' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Ingredients'

        },
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            'recipy_id' => true,
            'ingredient_id' => true,
            'quantity_id' => true,
            'amount' => true,
            'amount_in_gram' => true,
            'remark' => true,
            'grouping_term' => true,
            'version' => true,
            'recipy' => true,
            'ingredient' => true,
            'quantity' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'RecipyIngredients'

    },
    (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\RecipyIngredient) {

        'id' => (int) 2,
        'recipy_id' => (int) 1,
        'ingredient_id' => (int) 88,
        'quantity_id' => (int) 1,
        'amount' => '300',
        'amount_in_gram' => (int) 300,
        'remark' => 'Gewicht zonder schil',
        'grouping_term' => null,
        'version' => (int) 1,
        'created' => null,
        'modified' => null,
        'quantity' => object(App\Model\Entity\Quantity) {

            'id' => (int) 1,
            'name' => 'gram',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                'name' => true,
                'ingredients' => true,
                'recipy_ingredients' => true,
                'shoppinglist' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Quantities'

        },
        'ingredient' => object(App\Model\Entity\Ingredient) {

            'id' => (int) 88,
            'name' => 'banaan',
            'average_weight' => null,
            'recipy_id' => null,
            'quantity_id' => null,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                'name' => true,
                'average_weight' => true,
                'recipy_id' => true,
                'quantity_id' => true,
                'recipy' => true,
                'quantity' => true,
                'shoppinglist' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Ingredients'

        },
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            'recipy_id' => true,
            'ingredient_id' => true,
            'quantity_id' => true,
            'amount' => true,
            'amount_in_gram' => true,
            'remark' => true,
            'grouping_term' => true,
            'version' => true,
            'recipy' => true,
            'ingredient' => true,
            'quantity' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'RecipyIngredients'
    }
]

debug($entities);
[
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\RecipyIngredient) {

        '[new]' => true,
        '[accessible]' => [
            'recipy_id' => true,
            'ingredient_id' => true,
            'quantity_id' => true,
            'amount' => true,
            'amount_in_gram' => true,
            'remark' => true,
            'grouping_term' => true,
            'version' => true,
            'recipy' => true,
            'ingredient' => true,
            'quantity' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'RecipyIngredients'

    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, looked in the sources and the problem lay in the fact the table name was in `$this->request->data`.

I changed the patchEntities() line to:

```
$entities = $this->RecipyIngredients->patchEntities($list, $this->request->data['RecipyIngredients']);
```

and all was well!